# jest cannot resolve node modules subpath pattern imports

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

i build project using node express and using
https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_patterns to prevent "../../../xxx.js"

I added this to `package.json` and working perfectly

```
"imports": {
  "#src/*": "./src/*.js"
}
```

But the problem when i tried to running test from jest i got this error

```
Cannot find module '#src/config/database.js' from 'src/database/connection.js'

    Require stack:
      src/database/connection.js
      test/admin.test.js

      1 | import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
    > 2 | import databaseConfig from "#src/config/database.js";
        | ^


      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:311:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/database/connection.js:2:1)
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, tried to find solution from googling and documentation cannot find similar problem with this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this in your Jest Configuration (e.g. jest.config.json)

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "#src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
}
```

See the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) attribute in Jest configuration docs.

Comment: It seems like this trick won't work when you have a monorepo setup where if you have two projects, A and B and they both use the same alias within its code and then Project A imports Project B , then the alias will not work correctly.