# Cannot find module while using Subpath imports in mocha test

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger, mocha.js

In my project I installed `swagger-client` which in one of it's dependencies `@swagger-api/apidom-reference` uses Subpath imports in one of it's files.

`package.json`

```js
{
  ...,
  "imports": {
    "#buffer": {
      "node": {
        "import": "./es/util/polyfills/buffer/protocol-import.js",
        "require": "./cjs/util/polyfills/buffer/standard-import.cjs"
      },
      "default": "./cjs/util/polyfills/buffer/standard-import.cjs"
    },
  },
 ...
}
```

In my project, I use `swagger-client` and it works fine. However, in my mocha testing suite I noticed that the `swagger-client` import fails with the following error

```
 Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-reference/cjs/parse/parsers/binary/#buffer'
Require stack:
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-reference/cjs/parse/parsers/binary/index-node.cjs
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/resolver/strategies/openapi-3-1-apidom/resolve.js
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/resolver/strategies/openapi-3-1-apidom/index.js
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/index.js
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/node_modules/swagger-client/lib/commonjs.js
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/srcfiles/swaggers/OpenAPI.js
- /Users/dchicchon/Projects/myproject/master/mainProject/node_modules/@projectApp/submodule/test/unit/srcfiles/swaggers/OpenAPITest.js
```

The only "workaround" to this solution would be to comment out an import or replace it with the actual library in the @swagger-api/apidom-reference file

`/Users/dchicchon/Projects/project/release/myproject/node_modules/@myproject/submodule/node_modules/@swagger-api/apidom-reference/cjs/parse/parsers/binary/index-node.cjs`

```js
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.default = void 0;
// var _buffer = require("#buffer"); // commented out import here
// or
var _buffer = require('buffer'); // replaced with dependency rather than subpath import
```

I looked over the nodejs Subpath imports property here: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports and I am using a  version of node `16.0.0` that supports this property.

After looking at a similar SO question here: [jest cannot resolve node modules subpath pattern imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869339/jest-cannot-resolve-node-modules-subpath-pattern-imports), I am now assuming that this is an issue with Mocha and not `swagger-client`. In the question it uses `jest` and mentions the use of `moduleNameMappers` which I havent found for mocha.

Am I correct in saying this is the problem? And if so, how would I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Linking here the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/2899) where this has been dealt with. The current conclusion is that this must be local dev issue or issue with some local tooling. I've created a [POC repo](https://github.com/char0n/swagger-client-mocha), which serves as a prove that swagger-client >= 3.19.0 + mocha >= 10 work out of the box on fresh installs for Node.js >= 12.20.0.